# Calling applet method from JavaScript throws "undefined is not a function"

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

Here is how I create an applet in my html:

```
   <applet id="scanApplet" width="300" height="50">
        <param name="jnlp_href" value="launch.jnlp"/>
    </applet>
   <p>Applet version: <span id="appletVersion"></span></p>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
    _applet = document.getElementById("scanApplet");
     var version = document.getElementById("appletVersion");
     version.innerHTML = _applet.getVersion();
```

And next I got an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. It is occurred when invoking `_applet.getVersion();`

I open this page locally (ie from file:///C:/../page.html)

So how to make it work? May be it blocked for some security reasons (however Firefox tells that content is allowed)?

Comment: Seems that you don't have an element with `appletVersion` ID on your page. Please show us the full code of your `page.html`.